# Datetime2 to Datetime is throwing error, but no Datetimes are being passed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using entity framework to pass data to a table. On the View, I am collecting a date, but because the way the table is set up, dates are not passed to the database as dates. Instead, the day, month, and year are passed as individual values as ints. So, for 10/25/2019, you send 25, 10, 2019 all as ints over to populate separate columns. Nothing else has to do with dates.

However, when I try to saveChanges() it throws the following error:

> {"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

I've delt with this error before, when dateTimes were being passed, but I've never seen it when the database is not receiving a date time. Here is the model:

```
public partial class rbExperience
{
    public int rb_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> diver_no { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> skill_level { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> training { get; set; }
    public string instructor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> year_of_training { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> dives_last_12_months { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> last_rb_dive_month { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> last_rb_dive_day { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> last_rb_dive_year { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> num_hours { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> num_dives { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> max_dive_depth_life { get; set; }
}
```

This model was built with entity framework, so it's accurate to the database. I have access to the database, and can verify that no changes have been made, and no dates are in that table anywhere.

```
            rbExperience experience = new rbExperience()
            {
                rb_id = GeneralExperience.DiverNumber,
                diver_no = 1,
                dives_last_12_months = GeneralExperience.NumberOfDives,
                last_rb_dive_day = GeneralExperience.LastDive.Day,
                last_rb_dive_month = GeneralExperience.LastDive.Month,
                last_rb_dive_year = GeneralExperience.LastDive.Year,
                skill_level = skill,
                training = GeneralExperience.HasFormerTraining ? (byte)1 : (byte)2,
                instructor = GeneralExperience.Instructor,
                year_of_training = GeneralExperience.YearOfTraining,
                num_dives = (short)GeneralExperience.NumberOfDives
            };

            if (isSCUBA)
            {
                experience.max_dive_depth_life = (short)SCUBAExperience.MaxDiveDepth;

            }
            else
            {
                experience.max_dive_depth_life = (short)RBExperience.MaxDiveDepth;
                experience.num_hours = (short)RBExperience.HoursOnRebreather;
            };

                rbExperience retured = db.rbExperiences.Add(experience);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Here are 2 of the models I use for the View. var GeneralExperience comes from Experience class. (don't worry about the isSCUBA part. It is throwing the same error)

```
public class Experience
{
    [Display(Name = "Skill Level")]
    public List<SelectListItem> SkillLevels { get; set; }
    public string SkillLevel { get; set; }
    public bool HasFormerTraining { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Instructor Name")]
    public string Instructor { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Year of Formal Training")]
    public int YearOfTraining { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastDive { get; set; } 
    public int NumberOfDives { get; set; } 
    public int DiverNumber { get; set; }

}

public class RebreatherExperience
{
    [Display(Name = "How many hours on this Rebreather?")]
    public int HoursOnRebreather { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "What is the victim's maximum dive depth?")]
    public int MaxDiveDepth { get; set; } //Ever, not just for the once incident.
}
```

Comment: var moment = new DateTime(
                                GeneralExperience.LastDive.Year, GeneralExperience.LastDive.Month, GeneralExperience.LastDive.Day);  Then use the moment object since you know it's a DateTime and not a DateTime2. IE last_rb_dive_year = moment.Year

Comment: What is 'moment' supposed to be and how does this solve the issue? This is just creating a new DateTime that I already have in GeneralExperience.LastDive.

Comment: Does the model binder that creates the GeneralExperience actually create a DateTime or a DateTime2?

Comment: GeneralExperience isn't from entity framework, only the rbExperience is. The other Model I use for the View, and was handmade. So the db doesn't have any idea that it even exists

Comment: Check for triggers, calculated columns, or indexed views.